# dockerfile and bad RUN

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My dockerfiles builds images without error but some RUNs given’t result in the container. For example, in this dockerfile, it is the line with the sed:

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Installer apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y -q && apt-get dist-upgrade -y -q
RUN apt-get install -y -q apache2
RUN apt-get -y -q autoclean && apt-get -y -q autoremove

# Activer ssl et générer la clé et le certificat autosigné
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN a2ensite default-ssl
RUN make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil 

# Activer les fichiers .htaccess
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN sed 's/ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost/ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost\n\t\tAllowOverride all/' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

# donner les droits d’accès à apache
RUN chown -R www-data: /var/www/html/

VOLUME /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

An other example where the bad RUN are the line with rm and chown commands:

```
FROM perso/apache

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Installer php5 et les modules tiers
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y -q && apt-get dist-upgrade -y -q
RUN apt-get install -y -q php5 php5-mysql php5-gd php5-curl
RUN apt-get -y -q autoclean && apt-get -y -q autoremove

# Donner les droits d’accès à apache
RUN rm /var/www/html/index.html
COPY volumes/Leed-master/ /var/www/html/
RUN chown -R www-data: /var/www/html/

VOLUME /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: I don't know, what _is_ the problem? Can you explain what are you expecting vs what is happening?

Comment: a sidenote `&& apt-get upgrade -y -q && apt-get dist-upgrade -y -q` is useless, and you should group your RUN, see the Dockerfiles best practice https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: by the way, you already have many Apache ready docker images, see for example https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/apache/ or more generally https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=apache&starCount=0

Comment: For the first example, the line "\n\t\tAllowOverride all"isn’t added in the container. For the second example, the file index.html isn’t remove and the owner is always root.